# How to show a list of Play2 compile errors in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a Play2 application in IntelliJ. I'd like to get a list of compile errors in the Project inside of IntelliJ (in the Problems view?)

I've created the project using activator `activator new my-first-app play-scala` and Imported it into IntelliJ using the SBT import feature. I can run the application just fine.

Now I've introduced a compile error like this (2 Objects in 2 different files)

```
object TestObject1 {
  def doSomething() = {
    TestObject2.computeSomething(1)
  }
}

object TestObject2 {
  def computeSomething(a:Int, b:Int) = a+b+1
}
```

(note that doSomething attempts to only pass a single parameter to computeSomething)

I can see this error highlighted when looking at the editor tab containing `TestObject1`, the Problems view however remains empty. Pressing compile does not fix this. Running the application is still possible and I get the corresponding compile error shown in the browser.

[image: IntelliJ screenshot showing the Problem]

Note that while the example here shows Scala code the Problem also occurs with Java code.

Is there a way to get the compile error show in a list inside of IntelliJ?